# add file in initial commit without creating new commit

Tags: git

I have made 10 commits and each commit have been already pushed to central repository. Lets suppose i have commits for example.

> C1-C2-C3-C4-C5

where C5 was my last commit and all commits have been pushed. The branch i master. I want to delete the history and want to keep my last commit in git logs. I don't want anyone can reset head to any previous commit or push.

someone's told me to use `git rebase -i head~4` but i want to make my sense clear, before implementing it.

I have implement following commands

```
git checkout --orphan newB
git add -A
git commit
git branch -D master
git branch -m master
git push
```

and after these above commands my git graph become as per given image below

[image: git graph]

Current graph of my repository is look like this

[image]

Look the first two commits and it is detached from master. And i want t go to the encircled hash.
git rebase giving me following error

```
$ git rebase -i head~5
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream head~5
```

Comment: 'git rebase' is the right answer.

Comment: how can i use git rebase

Comment: @ASyedFahad firs, you need to be onto the same branch where you're trying to rebase on, second, you should use `head~<n>` where `<n>` is number of commits behind this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rewrite your first commit, you should not specify an `upstream` commit.  (The first upstream commit you could provide is your first commit, which would begin rewriting *from* the first commit, instead of *including* the first commit.)

Instead, you can use `--root` which indicates that you want to begin rewriting from the root of the branch, which will allow you to rewrite the first commit.

For example:

```
% git log --oneline
072c8fc Modification 3 to master
9bdb3a2 Modification 2 to master
45f0758 Modification 1 to master
96da320 Initial revision
```

Specifying an `upstream` of `96da320` (or `HEAD~3`) will not allow you to rewrite the first commit.  Similarly, you cannot specify `HEAD~4` since that would refer to your first commit's parent, which of course does not exist.

Instead, if you use the `--root` flag:

```
% git rebase -i --root
```

Then your interactive rebase script will contain the root commit:

```
pick 96da320 Initial revision
pick 45f0758 Modification 1 to master
pick 9bdb3a2 Modification 2 to master
pick 072c8fc Modification 3 to master
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rebase -i head~5` instead of `git rebase -i head~4`

---

### What rebase is used for?

It's used to apply commits on top of history but, in some case (such this) is used also to rewrite the history

---

### What is -i flag?

It is used to start an interactive process where an editor (such vi) will be showed to you and where you can choose from different options

---

### Why head~5

Because you need to rewrite history for last five commits

---

### What should I do next?

With interactive rebasing, something like this will be showed to you

```
pick 9e40be3 First commit message
pick 6e20a2a Second commit message
pick 0b06199 Third commit message
pick 3b4d266 Fourth commit message
pick c273e2f Fifth commit message
```

and below

```
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

where `c273e2f` (for instance) is the hash that identify a commit.

Now you can choose what to do with your commits. If you need first four commits to be only one, you can apply either a `fixup` or a `squash` (see commands above).

With `fixup` you won't be able to "travel" commits messages and only first commit message (or to be honest the commit message for commit you're fixing up) will be taken.

With `squash` you can choose what message to keep and even edit them (another "editor page" will be showed to you if this is chosen methodology).

A working example for you could be something like

```
pick 9e40be3 First commit message
f 6e20a2a Second commit message
f 0b06199 Third commit message
f 3b4d266 Fourth commit message
pick c273e2f Fifth commit message
```

This will result in two commits (first with second-third-fourth "merged" and fifth) where first commit will have first original commit message whether fifth commit will have fifth original commit message

---

### Pay attention

As you are going to rewrite history, when you push, you need to specify `-f` as flag and if you're doing this in a "public" branch (such `dev`, or `master`, or whatever) this could be a pain in the back for who needs to push to that branch aswell.

Comment: `HEAD~5` would refer to a non-existent commit since your first commit does not have a parent.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: i perfectly know but OP's edited question AFTER my answer and now I don't have time to edit it :)